# random_bytes can be unique ? collision percentage?

Tags: php

I searched here, but I found nothing about my question. So, here I am posting this *beginner-like* question. Is `random_bytes()` can be unique ? is it collision proof? or at least percentage of collision ? that's all thank you.

Comment: No random_bytes is not guaranteed unique.... randomness and uniqueness aren't the same thing: if you toss a coin in the air, how many unique values are there? If you call random_bytes with an argument of 1, how many unique values are there? What random_bytes is is random and not predictable

Comment: Thank  you @MarkBaker ,what can I add to make `random_bytes()` unique on my db ?

Comment: btw, how youtube manage to do a unique `random_bytes()` then ? because that's what they're using in their browser for fetching the video right?

Comment: The only way you can guarantee uniqueness is to generate a value and check if it already exists on your database, storing it there if it doesn't, generating and rechecking a new value if it does..... if you generate a long enough value, the probability of a clash reduces, but it will only ever be zero the very first time

Comment: thank you @MarkBaker, btw, I tried to generate a random_byte then check, but I seem don't know to code it properly, I do that through a while loop ? can you give me some code to ? automatically generate a random_byte until it is unique in database then store that random_byte ?

Comment: i had a problem that fetching data in db while in a loop, does some loading, and causes problems

Answer (score 5):

According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php):

> Generates an arbitrary length string of cryptographic random bytes that are suitable for cryptographic use

So you can assume uniqueness, of course depending on the length of generated string. If you need to generate ID, then look at UUIDv4 e.g., and follow its generation algorithm, then you should be mostly safe.

Comment: I just want to try to do in the youtube, like www.youtube.com?watch=gUKr9XK4ma4, but how they do that if the `random_bytes()` is not unique ?

Comment: Look at explanations here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Answer (score 3):

depends on how many samples you have. lets say you have 2**32 samples, ie the max number of rows you can have with MySQL's `INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY`, the chance of a **single** birthday-paradox-collision is, depending on how many bytes you have:

```
2 bytes (16 bits): 100.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
3 bytes (24 bits): 100.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
4 bytes (32 bits): 100.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
5 bytes (40 bits): 100.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
6 bytes (48 bits): 100.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
7 bytes (56 bits): 99.9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999974277905506997710587292686339838902053735038700
8 bytes (64 bits): 39.3469340216757114443741147076524842535626297825119964120927656555694024010908849471206150350857576700
9 bytes (72 bits): 0.1951218892070667250691497618471341831283295867954105629289252904440205299685786313768276645954696700
10 bytes (80 bits): 0.0007629365425717214706546969135582274422418854676363968117948350144755994256511242528910872277978400
11 bytes (88 bits): 0.0000029802321936667213364915605164519421014838352168471986663538895912445823072181581020658714403100
12 bytes (96 bits): 0.0000000116415321793053496565701278938242180316180229154385854539613876581244379897746327435643373700
13 bytes (104 bits): 0.0000000000454747350780481602973028357258824524741808886645719662583624822340299760166371533522862700
14 bytes (112 bits): 0.0000000000001776356838986658580689920341771905249751487982825962897403206620033498485817835300659600
15 bytes (120 bits): 0.0000000000000006938893902291641219700815236415536973326707821666710799551368023517110331739557467100
16 bytes (128 bits): 0.0000000000000000027105054305826723608319686584071090612151716924874531166001386472295273703307943900
17 bytes (136 bits): 0.0000000000000000000105879118382135639094920963639717342367514169992334119994205609169765348700055000
18 bytes (144 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000413590306180217340207731884661994264643204800215944245231226111034388785296700
19 bytes (152 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000001615587133516473985229467482865854604918557525775081822180266458433233768500
20 bytes (160 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000006310887240298726504781880555495324182972214491567209876737141250404779600
21 bytes (168 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000024651903282416900409251509930277214040045879950791758797419961100446700
22 bytes (176 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000096296497196941017224000648308071750262313022774985636346295341923700
23 bytes (184 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000376158192175550848525607074969627342466723345527152673112010015400
24 bytes (192 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000001469367938185745502077497353638838041947981767579266263262484300
25 bytes (200 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000005739718508538068367607380245230866731819297069453628708059800
26 bytes (208 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000022420775423976829560312306451660097730814868981669950354800
27 bytes (216 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000087581153999909490468506273382135243039566652995353267000
28 bytes (224 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000342113882812146447145140572235690531714961455513974300
29 bytes (232 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001336382354734947059183940911779352100739447565046900
30 bytes (240 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005220243573183386949861632625818803905141244681700
31 bytes (248 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020391576457747605273239632510419320514419007900
32 bytes (256 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000079654595538076583100463431089878263573867700
33 bytes (264 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000311150763820611652731146870615334746084900
34 bytes (272 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001215432671174264268459900465860940311000
35 bytes (280 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004747783871774469798732096132207018400
36 bytes (288 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000018546030749119022650939250161419400
37 bytes (296 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000072445432613746182231915763612700
38 bytes (304 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000282989971147446024342031727400
39 bytes (312 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001105429574794711032570163000
40 bytes (320 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004318084276541839970990100
41 bytes (328 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016867516705241562386800
42 bytes (336 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000065888737129849853100
43 bytes (344 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000257377879413476000
44 bytes (352 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001005382341458900
45 bytes (360 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003927274771300
46 bytes (368 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000015340917100
47 bytes (376 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000059925500
48 bytes (384 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000234100
49 bytes (392 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900
50 bytes (400 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

i'd say 10 bytes is a pretty good bet, 10 gives you ~0.0007% chance of a single birthday collision, which means if you made 142,856 such completely-maxed-out-databases, you would find approximately 1 collision!

but what if you have 2**64 samples, the max you can store with MySQL's `BIGINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY` ?
well, the chance of a **single** birthday-paradox-collision is

```
2 bytes (16 bits): 100.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
3 bytes (24 bits): 100.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
4 bytes (32 bits): 100.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
5 bytes (40 bits): 100.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
6 bytes (48 bits): 100.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
7 bytes (56 bits): 100.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
8 bytes (64 bits): 100.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
9 bytes (72 bits): 100.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
10 bytes (80 bits): 100.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
11 bytes (88 bits): 100.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
12 bytes (96 bits): 100.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
13 bytes (104 bits): 100.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
14 bytes (112 bits): 100.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
15 bytes (120 bits): 99.9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999974277906273575851562551628356447378966618610200
16 bytes (128 bits): 39.3469340287366576382767925051732039111443153312804614295448573882265327272181291266477621149279583500
17 bytes (136 bits): 0.1951218892524527289843252381047865603764957222291271541480405006250432867062615884385798395379814800
18 bytes (144 bits): 0.0007629365427493557992860364860221112540909113715577924612454205239852919524216540352421599644821300
19 bytes (152 bits): 0.0000029802321943606107060124716601695555770480242114789127059106834577558114278058404382818849390000
20 bytes (160 bits): 0.0000000116415321820158550869336177541161192708042329396354372821407046099857585335768804584013669800
21 bytes (168 bits): 0.0000000000454747350886360721356472707553077383794388148388467031092149898899242894843511891589892000
22 bytes (176 bits): 0.0000000000001776356839400248886867060739748432641003887840996012082625529387068758566288828246623200
23 bytes (184 bits): 0.0000000000000006938893903907228353122013439546439654554534861148024868828951568601096253132705644900
24 bytes (192 bits): 0.0000000000000000027105054312137610848504151844244226582645015901891537094464883977706983309067526600
25 bytes (200 bits): 0.0000000000000000000105879118406787542380559818153552580761590493204820090151213597342039664118779500
26 bytes (208 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000413590306276513837412019011322033428139921844672864993463944210874339175696900
27 bytes (216 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000001615587133892632177363699581708083450556373782285492737794813680820086690800
28 bytes (224 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000006310887241768094442873768259672103428738043488813587964420920500179336500
29 bytes (232 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000024651903288156618917904277536152490969617930133521422178837855248989900
30 bytes (240 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000096296497219361792646668335845222979331712244829793887159929935484900
31 bytes (248 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000376158192263132002532368596032914379779622178807755678094035179900
32 bytes (256 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000001469367938527859384926580837241064625725400753694854192313141500
33 bytes (264 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000005739718509874450722276514189516525055697225162842123281183600
34 bytes (272 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000022420775429197073133502632535983656519454594026157465249600
35 bytes (280 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000087581154020301066928862714348183649721268304345914487000
36 bytes (288 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000342113882891801042684266036993809630797496883272904900
37 bytes (296 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001336382355046097823016484384004566655778216477125900
38 bytes (304 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005220243574398819621132515461399494807301758736400
39 bytes (312 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020391576462495389144755614630195814541560310100
40 bytes (320 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000079654595556622613846940286552600807168740500
41 bytes (328 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000311150763893057085342114209801516894280100
42 bytes (336 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001215432671457254239609298286726606327700
43 bytes (344 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004747783872879899373468521962698428000
44 bytes (352 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000018546030753437106927740795504373200
45 bytes (360 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000072445432630613698935821187794700
46 bytes (368 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000282989971213334761469181164800
47 bytes (376 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001105429575052088912010822600
48 bytes (384 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004318084277547222312489700
49 bytes (392 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016867516709168837158600
50 bytes (400 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000065888737145190770100
51 bytes (408 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000257377879473401400
52 bytes (416 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001005382341693000
53 bytes (424 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003927274772200
54 bytes (432 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000015340917100
55 bytes (440 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000059925500
56 bytes (448 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000234100
57 bytes (456 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900
58 bytes (464 bits): 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

- now 18 bytes seems like a pretty good bet, you'd have a ~0.0007% chance of a **single** collision. personally i might go with 20 bytes instead though, just because SHA1 is 20 bytes, which would give you a 0.00000001% chance of collision. ofc you could go batshit crazy and use 58 bytes, which would give you ****less**** than a  0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001% chance of collision. (but that's just a waste of diskspace. my guess is that anything above 20 bytes is just a waste of diskspace)

this was calculated using [Decimal.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/decimal.js/10.3.1/decimal.min.js) with this formula:

```
function collision_chance2(samples,number_of_possible_hashes){
    var Decimal100 = Decimal.clone({ precision: 100, rounding: 8 });
    var k=Decimal100(samples);
    var N=Decimal100(number_of_possible_hashes);
    var MinusK=Decimal100(samples);
    MinusK.s=-1;
    var ret=((MinusK.mul(k.sub(1))).div(N.mul(2))).exp();
    ret=ret.mul(100);
    ret=Decimal100(100).sub(ret);
    return ret.toFixed(100);
}
```

Algorithm credits goes to Jeff Preshing, Canadian computer programmer: https://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities/

Answer (score 2):

I made a totally unscientific test using this script:

```
<?php

// collisions.php -- check collisions of random_bytes()

set_time_limit(0);

if(count($argv) < 2) die("Usage: php collisions.php n\n       where n is the number of tries\n");

$tries = floatval($argv[1]);
if($tries < 1) die("Number of tries must be at least 1.\n");

$t = time();

$chkUnqiue = [];
for($i = 0; $i < $tries; $i++) {
   $r = bin2hex(random_bytes(16));
   if(isset($chkUnique[$r]))
      $chkUnique[$r]++;
   else
      $chkUnique[$r] = 0;
}

$t = time() - $t;

echo "Collisions by random_bytes() after " . number_format($tries) . " tries: " .
     array_sum($chkUnique) .
     "\nTook approx. $t sec.\n";
```

And tried it for up to 30 million runs:

```
php collisions.php 30000000
```

And the output was:

```
Collisions by random_bytes() after 30,000,000 tries: 0
Took approx. 53 sec.
```

Beyond 30 million, it started throwing `out of memory` errors. Running in CLI mode, I had the memory limit set to -1 (unlimited) so I had no room for larger tests on that server ... maybe someone can confirm no collisions on larger number of trials?

Comment: you'd use less RAM by using false instead of 0 (false needs 1 byte to store, int(0) needs 4 bytes on 32bit CPUs, and 8 bytes on 64bit CPUs) - you could use even less RAM by using null instead of bool, as null needs kink-of 0 bytes to store (then PHP just stores the variable type, not the variable value, all types, int, bool, and null, have the variable type stored, but int is 4-8 extra bytes, bool is 1 extra byte, and null is 0 extra bytes) - but with null you'd need to use array_key_exists(), which is slower than isset()

Answer (score 0):

Random, it does not guarantee a unique! 
The basic problem:
unique text, may be unique for how many people?

**For Example:**

The numbers in the range 1-9, distributed to 9 people uniquely. But does not a unique number to the tenth person.

You must write own unique byte function. If you can use md5() and uniqid() functions, you can generate a unique 32 character length, hexdecimal key.

**For Example:**

```
$uid = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
```

If you need more length for a unique key, you can use mcrypt_encrypt() function. You, sometimes, use to microseconds with a random number ( such as mt_rand() function ) for generate a unique key

Comment: [md5 doesn't guarantee uniqueness either](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Collision_vulnerabilities), in fact it's a relatively high probability of clashes compare with some other hashing algorithms

Comment: youtube format id is not hexdecimal. its base 36. you can create from decimal id via base_convert(number,frombase,tobase) function. For example: base_convert(364554,10,36) gives, 7tai code

Answer (score 0):

I use bin2hex + random_bytes to create random strings e.g.

- If you just need a unique ID, use bin2hex(random_bytes(16)). It's simple and strictly better than UUIDv4.
- If you explicitly need to interoperate with UUIDs or are likely to need in the future, use UUIDs.

**For example:**

```
$uuid = bin2hex(random_bytes(16));
```

[According to Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/8n819d/uuids_are_obsolete/).  And we know, it's true if it's on Reddit

In reaction to Daniel Wu's comment. It could well not be unique enough. PHP developers think it's sufficient though. [Read the recommended answer on post for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48628985/is-it-cryptographically-secure-to-use-bin2hexrandom-bytesstr).

Comment: say I need to generate 8 or 10 characters can I use the above function bin2hex(random_bytes(10)). Will this enable uniqueness?

Comment: Speaking from my own experience, bin2hex(random_bytes(16)) is not unique. After testing it to large amount of users (about 1000) some of them got same exact value. It's strange, considering 16 bytes is a long number, but it happened.

Comment: I agree Daniel, I would use 32 or 64 bytes for more randomness. I've edited my answer though. It's up to the programmer to decide if it's random enough for their purpose.