# Is it cryptographically secure to use bin2hex(random_bytes($str))?

Tags: php, security, encryption, cryptography, byte

I found different answers for this question but none of them ask about **cryptographic** security.

Is it cryptographically secure to use  `bin2hex(random_bytes($str))` in PHP? Will it decrease security or uniqueness?

Comment: In PHP7 that's about as good as you're going to get

Comment: I think it really depends on what you are using it for?

Comment: (vaguely off-topic) Does `$str` contain an integer?

Comment: Secure for what?

Comment: yes str contans integer @salathe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The documentation for `random_bytes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php) says that the function

> Generates an arbitrary length string of cryptographic random bytes that are suitable for cryptographic use, such as when generating salts, keys or initialization vectors.

so the PHP developers believe it's good enough. The input should be a number of bytes, not a string:

> ```
> string random_bytes ( int $length )
> ```

`bin2hex` has no impact on the cryptographic suitability of the generated data. In particular, it *cannot* "stretch" your random bytes into a larger amount of random bytes. If you need `$n` bytes of random data, use `random_bytes($n)`.

Comment: `bin2hex` has no impact? Don't most keys and iv's need to be a specific size of bytes... and thus 32 random_bytes are better than 32 bytes that are only a-f0-9 (half the result from bin2hex)? Just curious.

Comment: @IncredibleHat so bin2hex has impact? or not?

Comment: @IncredibleHat, `bin2hex` will indeed output a string that can use a smaller variety of characters than what `random_bytes` generates. But the string will be much longer. Both representations represent the same number of randomly-generated bytes.

Comment: Right, I was just curious though, since (for example) openssl_encrypt, takes a key of 32 length, if you chop a `bin2hex(random_bytes(32))` in half for that, you are essentially cutting your key down to 16 random bytes. So, it just make me think, and ... well ... ponder!

Comment: I guess it depends on the crypto usage in the end. Which, I don't know from the original question. Sorry to derail your answer with this, side track wonderings ;)

Comment: @IncredibleHat, you do have to be careful how you interpret the data. Some given number of bytes is, at the end of the day, just a corresponding number of zeroes and ones. `bin2hex` outputs a value that should be interpreted as a hexadecimal number, not a string. As long as you factor that into how you use the variable you should be good to go. (The key is that `bin2hex` cannot add entropy.)

Comment: what if I use `bin2hex(random_bytes(32))` and then use it as a key (2x longer string) for `bcrypt` algorithm, will attacker need to guess 64 string or 32 string? or it will not be that unique anymore?

`bin2hex(random_bytes(32))` vs `(random_bytes(64))` which one is more unique? and is uniqueness important in  `bcrypt`

Comment: @JohnRobertson, the amount of "randomness" you get comes from `random_bytes()`. `bin2hex()` doesn't generate any randomness. If you need 64 bytes of random data, use `random_bytes(64)`. "Uniqueness" doesn't make much sense in this context, but `random_bytes(64)` gives you twice as much random data as `bin2hex(random_bytes(32))`.